# "Show in Navigator" missing in 2020-03 update

Tags: java, eclipse

I prefer to see things in Navigator view although it is being deprecated. (For reasons I'm not aware.)

In the latest 2020-03 update when I right click on a Java class and try to *Show In > Navigator*, it's not present any more. I feel package explorer is more Java centered and prefer Navigator. Is there still a way to enable this view in the latest update?

[image: navigator missing in show in]

Comment: Is the *Navigator* view present in your Eclipse installation? Can you see it is the view list if you navigate to *Window > Show View > Other...*?

Comment: Yes. Window > Show View > Navigator exists. Just Show in > Navigator doesn't exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed that the contents of the *Show In* sub-menu is different in different perspectives.

Try to switch to the *Java* perspective, *Window >  Perspective > Open Perspective > Java*.

In my copy of Eclipse 2020-3 I have the *Navigator* entry in the *Show In* sub-menu when the Java perspective is active:

[image]

---

I noticed in the following Eclipse bug ticket that the *Navigator* view is to be removed eventually:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=550379

---

The *Navigator* view gives a "raw", unmodified view of the file system. The *Project Explorer* view can be used in a similar way by changing the following view preferences:

- *Filters preferences > Content > Java Elements >* Uncheck
- *Filters preferences > Pre-set filters >* Deselect all
- *View preferences > Project Presentation > Hierarchical*

Filter preferences button:

[image: Filter preferences button]

---

*Navigator* view is deprecated because it duplicates the *Project Explorer*, and the latter is more customizable for users and developers, and is also part of the [Common Navigator Framework](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Common_Navigator_Framework).

Answer (score 0):

Yes , has been deprecated.
The most similiar that I found is Project Explorer > Package Presentation (click on the three dots menu)> Hierarchical.

And the same Hierarchical option for Project Presentation menu option.

You will see a "tree view" of projects, packages similar to older Navigator View
(I am using Eclipse IDE 2023-09 (4.29.0))

Hope Helps.

Answer (score -1):

Windows -> show view -> navigator ( if not showing in list ,go to others and search )

worked for me.